# Laravel eloquent Group by belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two models: Student and StudentArchive as below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;


class Student extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['school_id', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'admin_number', 'archival_status'];

    public function student_archives(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentArchive::class);
    }
}
```

StudentArchive:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class StudentArchive extends Model{

    protected $casts = ['student_id' => 'int'];

    protected $fillable = ['student_id', 'class_of'];

    public function student(): BelongsTo{
        
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
    }
}
```

I have the `Student` Model with the student details. Once a student graduates, I add their student_id to the `StudentArchive` model and the `year` of graduation.

I would want to get the count of students in the `StudentArchive` model per year hence groupby `class_of` which is YEAR eg 2022, 2021 e.t.c.

I have tried as below but the count is wrong, it gets one count for all. Anyone?

```
 StudentArchive::withCount(['student' => function($query) {
        return $query->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id)
        ->where('archival_status', true);  }])
        ->groupBy('class_of')
        ->get();
```

Comment: You have a many to one relationship from StudentArchive to Student, therefore, the count does everything based on student_id and your query would work if it was a One to Many Relationship. In order to retrieve the count of students based on year, you don't have to do it with the relation at all. You can retrieve it directly by querying StudentArchive table only. Something like: `StudentArchive::select('class_of', DB::raw('count(*) as count_students'))->groupBy('class_of')->get()` and if you have where conditions to be checked for Student relations, you can uise `whereHas` or `whereExists`

Comment: @AkmalArzhang how do I factor in the where clause, especially for the school_id in the student model? Should be specific per school.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use a whereHas. Something like: `StudentArchive::whereHas(['student' => function ($q) { $q->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id)->where('archival_status', true); }])->select('class_of', DB::raw('count(*) as count_students'))->groupBy('class_of')->get()`. Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: Robert, I would be happy if you could accept my answer. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a many to one relationship from StudentArchive to Student, therefore, the count does everything based on student_id and your query would work if it was a One to Many Relationship. In order to retrieve the count of students based on year, you don't have to do it with the relation at all. You can retrieve it directly by querying StudentArchive table only, and if you have where conditions to be checked for Student relations, you can use `whereHas` or `whereExists`.

Something like:

```
StudentArchive::whereHas('student', function ($q) { 
        $q->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id)
            ->where('archival_status', true); 
        }
    )
    ->select('class_of', DB::raw('count(*) as count_students'))
    ->groupBy('class_of')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think WhereHas expects a String i.e `whereHas('student', function ($q)` edit accordingly

Comment: @Robert exactly. My bad. I was typing with phone and copied your query's `withCount` part. Didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing out. Fixed now.

Comment: you have a `PHP` syntax error here `whereHas('student' => function ($q) { $q->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id) ->where('archival_status', true); } )` and that should be `whereHas('student', function ($q) { $q->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id) ->where('archival_status', true); } )` (this ` =>` is used in arrays but you didn't specify one).